# How's it possible that ingress-nginx create a LoadBalancer in a Bare Metal K8s Cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, load-balance, ingress

I have a bare-metal k8s cluster. I set up Ingress Nginx + MetalLB because, if I understood correctly, Ingress Nginx can't provide a LoadBalancer. Everything was working right until I realized that, if I wipe out everything and reinstall without MetalLB, ingress is still able to provide a LoadBalancer and the ExternalIP is right.

Am I missing something? is it possible to expose a LoadBalancer service in a bare-metal server just with Ingress Nginx?